# How can I tell a component to wait for all the element's component to load in A-Frame?

Tags: aframe

I've read about initialization, and using the component's init. I also know that you can specify the dependencies in a component. But what if I don't know which are the dependencies, and what if I want to have a component loaded last because it depends on the other's elements properties?

For example, I'm currently working on a collider that works on multiple mesh names. Right now, the colliders I've seen (from Dmarcos, Super-Hands) I see that they read it using getObject3D('mesh'). I've created some custom elements with threejs and I've specified different meshes name. I'd like to read all the meshes that are set by the different components for my collider to work.

But for that, I need to wait for all the meshes of all the components. Is there a way for me to know, when all the components have been loaded in an entity?

There are a couple of solutions that are occurring to me right now:

1. Manually add the dependencies of the components that I'm writing. This would solve the issue temporarily, but I wouldn't be able to publish the component to GitHub.
2. Wire manually to each component that I have an event listener that will fire after it has been loaded and set.
3. Write a component that will work as a loading mechanism. For that, I think I'd need to inject some sort of code (using prototype maybe?) to all the components, so I could fire a ready event.
4. Polling mechanism. I'd refrain the collider to load for a second, or keep polling until it finds a mesh (Could be problematic since it works in an asynchronous fashion).

Comment: I have to say, number 4 is super hacky (window.setTimeout for 4 seconds), but it's working. I'm open to other options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about looping over the entity's DOM attributes, checking if the attribute name is a component, waiting for it if it is a component with `componentinitialized` event if it's not loaded?

```
for (var i = 0; i < yourEntityEl.attributes.length; i++) {
  if (yourEntityEl.attributes[i].key in AFRAME.components) {
    // Wait for all to load (e.g., count them up and increment a counter or Promise.all).
  }
}
```

Comment: Sweet ! Thanks for the super fast response! I'm going to try that now!

Comment: I have another question. Is there a property in the component that tells me if it's initialized or not? Because there could be the possibility that the eventListener('componentinitialized') will never be fired if the component I was depending was already initialized.

Comment: `el.components.foo.initialized`

Comment: Awesome!!1 Thanks a bunch!

Comment: I know this is old. I tried using .key but was returning undefined. Using .localName does the trick.

Answer (score 7):

Another option would be, run your setup code the first time the `play()` method is called, instead of `init()`. Note that `play()` could be called again if the scene is paused and unpaused, so probably set a flag like `this.initialized = true` and check for that so you don't do the setup twice.